# Vue JS: reactive syntax

Tags: javascript, vue.js, methods, syntax

While I was trying to grasp reactivity fundamentals and its syntax I've encountered following problem. Consider this snippet:

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
   data: dataFunction,
   methods: {method1:  methodImpl}
})
var dataObj = {
    title: 'Holiday',
    author: 'Stanley Middleton',
    age: 45
}
function dataFunction (){
    return dataObj
}
var methodsObj = {
    method1:  methodImpl
    
}
function methodImpl (){
    this.title = 'Infinite Jest'
}
app.mount('#app')
```

and html behind it:

```html
<div id="app">
        [...]
        <div @click="method1">change book title</div>
</div>
```

This code works and I was able to extract `data` into separate function and object but how can I do it with `method` ?
This `methods: methodsObj` doesn't work - obviously. I want to be able to use my `methodsObj` in `createApp` initialization. Is it possible?
I know it is purely academic but such exercises help me understand syntax and object relations.

Comment: There's no specific syntax for Vue here. These are the basics of JS. It is `methods: methodsObj`. Also it doesn't make sense to define dataObj outside dataFunction, the reason why `data` is a function is that this allows to return a new object each time it's called and not share it between component instances

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, [`var`s are hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting#var_hoisting), but *their initializations are not*. [`function`s and their definitions are also hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting#function_hoisting). Your code relies on hoisting, which can be problematic.

Here's a visualization of the hoisting in your original working code:

```js
//  HOISTED DECLARATIONS
var dataObj = undefined;
function dataFunction (){
    return dataObj
}
var methodsObj = undefined;
function methodImpl (){
    this.title = 'Infinite Jest'
}
//  HOISTED DECLARATIONS

const app = Vue.createApp({
   data: dataFunction,
   methods: {method1:  methodImpl} // ✅ methodImpl declared above
})
// INITIALIZATION
dataObj = {
    title: 'Holiday',
    author: 'Stanley Middleton',
    age: 45
}
// INITIALIZATION
methodsObj = {
    method1:  methodImpl
}

app.mount('#app')
```

Now consider that same code, but replace `methods: {method1: methodImpl}` with `methods: methodsObj`:

```js
//  HOISTED DECLARATIONS
var dataObj = undefined;
function dataFunction (){
    return dataObj
}
var methodsObj = undefined;
function methodImpl (){
    this.title = 'Infinite Jest'
}
//  HOISTED DECLARATIONS

const app = Vue.createApp({
   data: dataFunction,
   methods: methodsObj // ❌ methodsObj undefined above, so method1 would be undefined in the app
})
// INITIALIZATION
dataObj = {
    title: 'Holiday',
    author: 'Stanley Middleton',
    age: 45
}
// INITIALIZATION
methodsObj = {
    method1:  methodImpl
}

app.mount('#app')
```

The issue with `methodsObj` in the example above can be fixed by declaring and initializing it **before** usage (which is generally a best practice):

```js
// declare and initialize vars here...
var dataObj = {
    title: 'Holiday',
    author: 'Stanley Middleton',
    age: 45
}
function dataFunction (){
    return dataObj
}
var methodsObj = {
    method1:  methodImpl
    
}
function methodImpl (){
    this.title = 'Infinite Jest'
}

// now, use the declarations from above
const app = Vue.createApp({
   data: dataFunction,
   methods: methodsObj
})

app.mount('#app')
```

And here's the visualization of the hoisting above:

```js
//  HOISTED DECLARATIONS
var dataObj = undefined;
function dataFunction (){
    return dataObj
}
var methodsObj = undefined;
function methodImpl (){
    this.title = 'Infinite Jest'
}
//  HOISTED DECLARATIONS

// INITIALIZATION
dataObj = {
    title: 'Holiday',
    author: 'Stanley Middleton',
    age: 45
}
// INITIALIZATION
methodsObj = {
    method1:  methodImpl
}

const app = Vue.createApp({
   data: dataFunction,
   methods: methodsObj // ✅ methodsObj declared and initialized above
})

app.mount('#app')
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/JjpRmOW?editors=1010)

One of the motivations of [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) and [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) (introduced in ES2015) was to avoid common bugs from `var` hoisting, such as you observed above. If you had used `const`/`let` instead of `var` in your original code, the compiler would've thrown an error, which might've signaled to you then that the declaration should be moved above the usage. Consider using a [linter that discourages the use of `var`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-var).